# Providing a method name in the log4j2 GelfLayout

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to include a calling method name as a separate field in the Gelf:

```
<Socket name="Graylog" protocol="udp" host="127.0.0.1" port="12201">
    <GelfLayout>
        <KeyValuePair key="method" value="%M"/>
    </GelfLayout>
</Socket>
```

But in the Graylog this field's value appears just as `%M`, no value substitution is happening.

I read the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html), but couldn't find anything about resolving message pattern placeholders in the custom fields.

I know that [logstash-gelf](https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf/#log4j2) can do this, but is it possible to do this without using an extra plugin, using the standard log4j2?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to show what ID the thread had, but just as you, I noticed that the text was treated as static text. I looked into this and acording to the documentation it should be possible to use patterns, but not in `<KeyValuePair>`

```
  <GelfLayout includeThreadContext="true" threadContextIncludes="loginId,requestId">
    %d %5p [%t] %c{1} %X{loginId, requestId} - %m%n
    <KeyValuePair key="additionalField1" value="constant value"/>
    <KeyValuePair key="additionalField2" value="$${ctx:key}"/>
  </GelfLayout>
```

Look at the second row, above. It looks as if it would be possible to use pattern placeholders as a general message. I have, however, not been able to get this to work, maybe the version I use is to old.

I have found out that Log4j2 does not currently support what we want. But it will do in the next version (2.15.0). I have no idea, how ever, when the next version will be released, se issue [LOG4J2-3041](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3041) for details.

References:

- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#GELFLayout
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3041